# Clarification on R, I, and J type Instruction formats in MIPS

Tags: microprocessor, cpu, register, mips

[image]

I would like some clarification on some concepts of register types, to know if I understand it correctly.

If I had a 32-bit CPU.

Would that mean that the max number of operations that can be executed by the CPU be: $$3\times2^{6} = 192$$

Also, would the number of registers in the CPU be:$$2^{5} = 32$$

Which would then make the main memory be: $$32 \times 4bits = 64 bits = 8bytes$$

Finally, the maximum size of the target address of the J-type would be:$$2^{26} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would that mean that the max number of operations that can be executed
>   by the CPU be: \$3\cdot 2^6 = 192\$

Not quite. The CPU needs to be able to distinguish whether an instruction is an R, I, or J type instruction from the opcode, so the number of opcodes is just \$2^6=64\$. However, the R type instructions also contain the 6 bit `funct` field which acts as another opcode field for the R type instructions. R type instructions always have an opcode field of `000000`, so your total number of instructions is \$2^6-1 + 2^6=127\$, because you have \$2^6\$ opcode encodings, but you use one to select the R type instruction, where you then have \$2^6\$ more instructions from the `funct` field.

> Also, would the number of registers in the CPU be: \$2^5=32\$

Yep, MIPS has 32 registers.

> Which would then make the main memory be:
>   \$32×4bits=64bits=8bytes\$

I'm not sure how you're getting this. The (maximum) size of main memory depends on how many bits are in an address * the smallest addressable unit. MIPS has 32 bit addresses (that's what a 32 bit cpu usually means), and the smallest addressable unit is 1 byte. That means the maximum amount of memory is $$2^{32}bytes = 4,294,967,296bytes = 4GiB$$

But how do you use a 32 bit address if there's only 5 bits per field in an instruction? MIPS is a Load-Store architecture, which means most instructions only interact with registers, and only load and store instructions can access memory. So for example, say I want to add 5 to the int stored at address 0x14859868:

```
lui $8, 0x1485      # load upper 16 bits into register 8
ori $8, $8, 0x9868  # load lower 16 bits into register 8
lw $9, 0($8)        # load register 9 with the contents of memory at 0x14859868
addi $9, $9, 5      # add 5 to the number in register 9
sw $9, 0($8)        # store the contents or register 9 to 
                    # the memory pointed to by register 8
```

Instead of specifying the address directly, I load the address into a register (`$8`) and use it as a pointer to access the memory.